# Specify multiple right subnets on libreswan ipsec vpn using ikev1

Tags: vpn, ipsec, libreswan

I want to connect to a ipsec vpn server, and it allows me to connect to different ips (not a ip range), lets say `y.y.y.1, y.y.y.2, y.y.y.3, y.y.y.4`.

I have the following config:

```
conn toing-to-toing
        type=tunnel
        authby=secret
        auto=start

        left=%defaultroute
        leftid=a.b.c.d
        leftsubnets={f.f.f.f/32,}
        rightsubnets={y.y.y.1/32, y.y.y.2/32, y.y.y.3/32, y.y.y.4/32,}
        leftnexthop=%defaultroute

        right=s.s.s.s
        rightnexthop=%defaultroute

        keyexchange=ike
        ike=aes256-sha1;dh18
        pfs=yes

        esp=aes256-sha1;dh18
        ikelifetime=28800s
        salifetime=3600s
```

This configuration works only with the first IP.

If I use only `rightsubnet` , each IP works perfectly. But I need to connect to all the IPs at the same time.

The VPN connection only works using IKEV1, and according to the [libreswan documentation](https://libreswan.org/man/ipsec.conf.5.html) and [strongswan documentation](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/FAQ#Multiple-subnets-per-SA) I *might* have to specify each connection separately in the following format:

```
conn toing-to-toing
        type=tunnel
        authby=secret
        auto=start

        left=%defaultroute
        leftid=a.b.c.d
        leftsubnets={f.f.f.f/32,}
        leftnexthop=%defaultroute

        right=s.s.s.s
        rightsubnet={y.y.y.1/32}
        rightnexthop=%defaultroute

        keyexchange=ike
        ike=aes256-sha1;dh18
        pfs=yes

        esp=aes256-sha1;dh18
        ikelifetime=28800s
        salifetime=3600s

conn-toing-to-toing2
        also=toing-to-toing
        rightsubnet={y.y.y.2/32}

conn-toing-to-toing3
        also=toing-to-toing
        rightsubnet={y.y.y.3/32}

conn-toing-to-toing4
        also=toing-to-toing
        rightsubnet={y.y.y.4/32}
```

Again, this only works ofor the first IP. I have, by now probably read nearly all the related documentation on the world wide web, but I cannot get the VPN to work for all the subnets at once.
What am I doing wrong?